# How to configure ADFS Endpoint Response URL using xml

Tags: logout, adfs, endpoint

I'm trying to add a relying party trust to `ADFS` by importing an `XML` file. This works great but I can't find the correct entry to add the Endpoint's `SAML` logout **Response URL** field.
In other words, I'm trying to find the match from red rectangle in the picture [SAML logout properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06lPW.png) to the correct attribute in the XML file.

For example:

```
<md:ThisiswhatImmissingBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://myserver.com/remote_auth/complete_logout/"/>
```

Any assistance will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The metadata file (the XML part) does not have to have all the endpoints.

So it was either left out or the RP doesn't support logout.

Comment: Thanks. What I want to find is what is the equivalent md: value that will fill the "Response URL" field in the Saml logout endpoint.